# Is there a best practice regarding a payload for socket.io acknowledgements?

Tags: sockets, socket.io

I'm working on the serverside on my first socket project. The team chose socket.io.

It provides functionality to fire an acknowledgement/callback back to the socket that is talking to it.

```
socket.on('anEvent', (payload, callback) => {
    doSomethingWith(payload);

    callback(true);
});
```

I like consistency, so I want to send back consistently shaped objects. For instance:

```
socket.on('anEvent', (payload, callback) => {
    const responseData = doSomethingWith(payload);

    callback({
        'status': 200,
        'data': responseData
    });
});
```

or

```
socket.on('anEvent', (payload, callback) => {
    try {
        const responseData = doSomethingWith(payload);

        if (!responseData) {
            callback({
                'status': 404
            });
        }
        
        callback({
            'status': 200,
            'data': responseData
        });
        
    } catch(error) {
        callback({
            'status': 500,
            'error': error.toString()
        });
    }
});
```

or similar. I would not submit code like this. Don't worry :D

However, I've been reading [socket server specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.4) and the status codes don't make much sense to me.

Is it crazy to use http response codes in a socket acknowledgement or is there no best practices regarding this?

Comment: I really don't see any reason to use http response codes for socket.io acknowledgements unless you're proxying an underlying operation that is actually HTTP and you want to just forward on those status.  If it's your own operation, then just create your own status codes that make sense for what you're doing.  In most cases, I would think the usual convention of an `err` value that is `null` for no error and contains an error code when there is an error would be simplest and a well understood strategy.

Comment: Appreciate the input. The idea of reusing the status was because other devs are already familiar with them and their meaning. However I do think that by reusing http codes it could cause confusion at some point down the line. I guess the answer to this question is: do what you think is best, but be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it crazy to use http response codes in a socket acknowledgement or is there no best practices regarding this?

I wouldn't say it's crazy, but I don't really see any reason to use http response codes for socket.io acknowledgements unless you're proxying an underlying operation that is actually HTTP and you want to just forward on that status.

If it's your own operation, then just create your own status codes that make sense for what you're doing just like you would be doing if you wrote a shared function that returned an error code. In most cases, I would think the usual convention of an err value that is null for no error and contains an error code or object when there is an error would be simplest way to go and a well understood strategy.

So, unless there's an underlying http operation that you're trying to pass on the status from, I think that reusing http status would just confuse folks, plus I rather doubt you'd find much to reuse so you'd be repurposing something that isn't a particularly good match and would likely be confusing.

I'd say that best practice is to define your own meaningful error return values and document them.  Keep in mind that you can use strings instead of numbers and they are often more descriptive that way.  You may also return an error object that contains both a code and a string (self describing).